# Buttons to up/downvote tag synonyms not visible when phone is in portrait mode

Tags: bug, user-interface, tag-synonyms, responsive-design

But are visible in landscape mode. I’m using an iPhone 12 Pro, Safari on iOS 14.4, I did not click ‘disable responsiveness’. Ak. In comments informs me that this is [reproduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnHlq.png) in Android 10. Here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I noticed the above in Math.SE but I don’t expect this to be only a problem there.

Comment: Reproduced on [Android 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnHlq.png)

Comment: Thanks @Ak. I have edited the question to add this